# Objects to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

All am trying to do is add objects to the list. But I don't know why I am getting an error with the line `shapetizer.add(circleone);`. Can anybody help me out please.

**Main**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    //create an empty list of shape objects
    ArrayList<Shape> shapetizer = new ArrayList<Shape>();

    //create 2 circle objects
    Circle circleone = new Circle(10);
    Circle circletwo = new Circle(20);

    //Add the created circles to the list
    shapetizer.add(circleone);

}
```

**Shape**

```
public abstract class Shape {

    // yet to be filled

}
```

**Circle**

```
public class Circle extends Shape {

    private float radius;

    public Circle(float radius) {
        super();
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Circle [radius=" + radius + "]";
    }

}
```

The errors I am getting for the line I mentioned above are:

- syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
- syntax error on token "circleone", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token

Comment: And the error is? Isn't it obvious that to understand why you get an error, the first thing to do should be to read it?

Comment: What error? Why would you leave that bit out? When do you expect the `add` method to be invoked? Why do you think so?

Comment: Try casting the object to shape. so ```shapetizer.add((Shape)circleone);```

Comment: Please add the exact error / error text to your question. Without the error information the question is considered off-topic. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What does the JVM execute when you type `java Main`?

Comment: Errors am getting are: (1) syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s); (2) syntax error on token "circleone", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Code is in the Main class not in a main method !

Comment: Thanks! Ticked your answer!